# ALL Links will be Active whenever they contain same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please Help me In this Regard...............
I want to active all the links based on the selection it means when i selected "First" element in the DropDown all the links which will contain id as "First" will be active other will be in unbind stage.............

Please Help Me..............

```
<select id="link" name="link">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="first">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="second">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="second">Link1</a>
<a href="#" id="first">Link1</a>

$('.selection').dropdown({
    onChange: function(value) {
        //Give Me suggestion for the Code......    
    }
});
```

when i selected the First then all the "First" id value links will be active....
Pleasse.......help me...........

Comment: `id` attribute should have a unique value in your page. You should use the `class` attribute instead.

Comment: explain me the code how can i resolve this please..............

Comment: What pluggin are you using for `dropdown`? Basically, you have to replace every `id` attributes by `class`. Then, in you `onChange` function, you could do something like `$('.' + value).css('color', 'red')`. This will change the color to red, of every link with the selected class. You have to provide more information if you want people to help

Answer (score 2):

First of all, either use unique ids or use other attributes like `class` or `data-id`. Give a class so that you can segregate this from other links on the page.

```
<select id="link" name="link">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>

<a href="#" data-id="first" class="link">Link1</a> 
<a href="#" data-id="second" class="link">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-id="second" class="link">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-id="first" class="link">Link1</a>
```

Now update the change event to

```
$('.selection').change(function() {

   var value = $(this).val();

   //first made all the links inactive
   $( ".link" ).unbind( "click" );

   //now bind the events to links which has same data-id value selected from drop-down
   $( ".link[data-id*='" + value + "']" ).bind( "click", function(){
      alert("link clicked");
   } );
   $( ".link[data-id" ).not("[data-id*='" + value + "']").bind( "click", function(){
      e.preventDefault();
   } );

});
```

Comment: i pasted the as it is but it was working on all links it was not disabling the links

Comment: @KalishavaliShaik try now

Comment: Thank you and I want to do it as data-id contains "first" then how can i do it as.you are giving the code for mapping exactly as data-id and i want to do it for contains data id.can you please.....help me

Comment: @KalishavaliShaik try jquery attribute contains selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Comment: @KalishavaliShaik made changes to include the `contains` logic. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html to contain classes for the links so the JQuery code will work.  I also fixed your on change event to work properly.

HTML:

```
<select id="link" name="link">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="first">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="second">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="second">Link1</a>
<a href="#" class="first">Link1</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#link').on("change",function(selection) {

        //get the value first or second
        var value = $(this).val();

        //do something with the selected class
        $("." + value).css("color","yellow");            

    });
```